# Ubuntu 16.04 says I have Intel processor but I am sure I have amd64

Tags: 16.04, graphics, 64-bit, intel, cpu

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 and it says I have Intel processor when I have AMD64 and says I have Intel graphics when I have ATI Radeon.  How do I correct this?

```
bauds@bauds-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 37
Model name:            Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU        P6200  @ 2.13GHz
Stepping:              5
CPU MHz:               2133.000
CPU max MHz:           2133.0000
CPU min MHz:           933.0000
BogoMIPS:              4256.61
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,1
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid popcnt lahf_lm dtherm arat
```

and

```
bauds@bauds-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor    Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
DeviceName: Video Graphics Controller
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
```

Comment: Where does it "say" that? AMD64 is a platform that is correct for Intel and AMD CPUs.

Comment: In Settings -> Details

Comment: What exactly does it say? Please also [edit] your question and add there output of `lscpu` and `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal commands.

Comment: Intel is a CPU. `amd64` is an instruction set, which both AMD and Intel CPUs implement for 64-bit consumer grade CPUs.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of your certainty you clearly have an Intel CPU. [This one](http://ark.intel.com/products/50176/Intel-Pentium-Processor-P6200-3M-Cache-2_13-GHz) to be precise.

Answer (score 3):

You have an Intel CPU and an integrated Intel GPU.

There is no ATI Radeon card in your system.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [link](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02711992) to the exact specifications to your laptop, which clearly states that it has an Intel CPU. I understand how this can get confusing sometimes especially when in linux it almost always says AMD when referencing a 64bit system.

Comment: Not having the rep to comment does not mean you can comment in the answer section. Don't do that. It so happens that this post does answer the question as the answer is "You are wrong, you have an Intel CPU".